# Don't re-use previous model run's user inputs

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I have a QGIS model with a Number input (though this applies to many if not all inputs)

When users enter a number in the model's dialog, run the model and then re-open the model dialog to run it again, the number entered in the previous invocation will be pre-entered in the dialog.

If I set a value as default, this behaviour does not change. The default value is not pre-entered, instead it is always the previously entered value.

How can I stop QGIS from doing that? I want the user to always see the default value.